# What relationship and difference are between `nix-env --install` and `nix-build`?

Tags: nixos, nix

What relationship and difference are between `nix-env --install` and `nix-build`?

Does `nix-env --install` build the derivatives specified to it, i.e. perform the job of `nix-build`?

Comment: It is explained in detail here: https://stop-using-nix-env.privatevoid.net/